# Weird problem with JSMock

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, foreach

Can someone explain what's going on here, and how to fix it? I'm using JSMock, and executing the following code in `spec.js`:

```
for (var t in []) {
    alert(t)
}
```

... causes my browser to alert "eachIndexForJsMock" (when it shouldn't execute the `alert` command at all). This is messing up my `for each` loops. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [JSMock augments the `Array.prototype` object](http://code.google.com/p/jsmock/source/browse/trunk/jsmock.js?spec=svn10&r=10#372).

The `for-in` statement is meant to be used to **enumerate** object properties, for arrays and array-like<sup>1</sup> objects, it is always recommended to use an *iterative* loop, e.g.:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  //...
}
```

You should avoid `for-in` on array-like objects because:

- The order of iteration is not guaranteed, the indexes may not be visited in the numeric order.
- Inherited properties are also enumerated.

See also:

- [Iteration VS Enumeration](http://dhtmlkitchen.com/?category=/JavaScript/&date=2007/10/21/&entry=Iteration-Enumeration-Primitives-and-Objects)

<sub>[ 1 ] By *array-like* I mean any object that contains sequentially numbered properties and a `length` property.</sub>

Comment: See: [Loop through array in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript/3010848#3010848) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Wow, that's really unintuitive. In my opinion, there should at least be another `foreach` construct that behaves the way it would behave in other languages, such as PHP. Thanks for your answer though!